# Boost Python overriding equality operator

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to override the python equality operator for a class which I expose via boost python.

So my code looks something like:

```
   class_<MyClass, boost::noncopyable, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >("MyClass", no_init)
    .def("foo", &MyClass::foo)                                    
     .
     .
     .
    .def("__eq__", &MyClass::operator==) 
    .def("__ne__", &MyClass::operator!=)
```

Yet in python when I take 2 instances of the object which represent the same C++ object, but have arrived from different python objects, they are never equal...

Hence:

```
from myPackage import myClass

v1 = myClass.get("abc")
v2 = myClass.get("abc")
if v1 == v2:
   print "true"
else:
   print "false"
```

Always prints false. (I omitted the get function definition from the object for simplicity sake)

Any ideas?

Comment: `MyClass.get()` returns a `MyClass` instance, of course?

Comment: Actually it is wrapped by a boost::shared_ptr: boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider writing a C++ test case for `MyClass::operator==()` to verify its implementation.  The Boost.Python code exposing the operators is correct.

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f1fa62b4fb867c) exposing a C++ class' comparison operators as the equality and inequality rich-comparison methods:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class foo
{
public:
  foo(const char* value) : value_(value) {}
  foo(const foo&) = delete;
  foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;

  bool operator==(const foo& rhs) 
  {
    std::cout << "foo::operator==()" << std::endl;
    return value_ == rhs.value_;
  }

  bool operator!=(const foo& rhs)
  {
    std::cout << "foo::operator!=()" << std::endl;  
    return !(*this == rhs);
  }

  std::string get_value() const     { return value_;  }
  void set_value(std::string value) { value_ = value; }

private:
  std::string value_;
};

boost::shared_ptr<foo> make_foo(const char* value)
{
  return boost::make_shared<foo>(value);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<foo, boost::shared_ptr<foo>, boost::noncopyable>(
      "Foo", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(&make_foo))
    .def("__eq__", &foo::operator==)
    .def("__ne__", &foo::operator!=)
    .add_property("value", &foo::get_value, &foo::set_value)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> foo1 = example.Foo("abc")
>>> foo2 = example.Foo("abc")
>>> foo3 = example.Foo("def")
>>> assert(foo1 == foo1)
foo::operator==()
>>> assert(foo1 == foo2)
foo::operator==()
>>> assert(foo1 is not foo2)
>>> assert(foo1 != foo3)
foo::operator!=()
foo::operator==()
>>> foo1.value = foo3.value
>>> assert(foo1 != foo2)
foo::operator!=()
foo::operator==()
>>> assert(foo1 == foo3)
foo::operator==()
```

As observed in the above output, the C++ comparison operators were called from Python.

---

In the example, the `make_foo()` factory function creates unique C++ `foo` instances.  Hence, I have opted to hide the implementation detail of the factory method to Python by wrapping `make_foo()` as a constructor and exposing it as the `__init__` method.  As [demonstrated here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12f179eba30937eb), equality can still be checked if object creation occurs through a static method.  On the other hand, if a static factory method like `get()` can return handles to existing `foo` instances, then one may expect that both equality and identity comparisons work on `Foo` Python objects (i.e. `assert(Foo.get("abc") is Foo.get("abc"))`.  To return a reference to the same Python object, one would need to manage the associated `PyObject`.

Comment: That's a good answer, and is basically what I was doing, I simply had a bug in the declaration of my comparison operator.

I was assuming that if I return shared_ptr<obj> from my get() func, than this is what boost will pass to the == operator in c++, hence I created the appropriate comparison in c++ to work with the shared_ptr wrapper, but in fact python was dereferencing my pointer and passing a const obj & to the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.def(self == self)
.def(self != self)
```

reference:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_operators_special_functions